# Why was Chaitanya Mahaprabhu an eka-dandi sanyasi despite being a Gaudiya Vaishnava?

Tags: advaita, chaitanya, gaudiya-vaishnavism

Advaitins Sanyasis are usually eka-dandi sanyasis while Vaishnava Sanyasis (including Gaudiya Vaishnava Sanyasis) are usually tri-dandi sanyasis. However, Chaitanya Mahaprabhu was a Gaudiya Vaishnava and like most Vaishnavas, an opponent of Advaita Vedanta. However, He was an eka-dandi Sanyasi. What is the reason for this?

Comment: It's because he was originally a shishya of an Advaita guru named Ishwara Puri.  It's only after that that he left Advaita and founded the Gaudiya Vaishnava sect.

Comment: Sorry, I got I mixed up.  Ishwara Puri was his Madhwa guru.  Keshava Bharati was his Advaita guru.  And I don't think you can change from an Ekadandi Sanyasi to a Tridandi Sanyasi.

Comment: Mahaprabhu wanted to preach the philosophy of devotion to Krishna. and for someone to accept His philosophy it was necessary that ppl respected Him.Advaitin Sanyasis were highly respected at that time. Thus He took Ekdandi sanyas. Mahaprabhu's danda was latter broken by Nityanand prabhu into 3 pieces signifying Vaishnav Sanyas and He threw it in ocean in Puri. Nityanand Prabhu thought Mahaprabhu is God Himself; why He needs a danda? :)

Comment: @Vishalprabhulawande some part of Mahaprabhu's danda is still there at Khardaha Shyama-Sundara Temple. So throwing all pieces to the river/sea is not acceptable.